# Dynamics crm - xrm events according to tab

Tags: tabs, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, xrm

I am using Dynamics crm 2016, I need to check some terms after unfocusing a tab:

for example:
I have 13 fields on a tab with null value, I need to show a message to the user only after these 13 fields are populated, I don’t want to attach the same event to each of the fields, I want to have a check only after the user leaves the specific tab.

Is it optimal in JS combining XRM/CRM? If it does how to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to mimic Business Process Flow (BPF) in the name of tab?

Comment: yes I want to use hide and show tabs, but according to fields changeEvent

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wire up to each of the 13 fields, an onChange handler that checks that all of the values are populated, and then displays the message.  So it would be the same function, just triggered for each of the 13 fields.

Answer (score 1):

I would attach the same event to those field. Remember the KISS principle. Keep it stupid and simple.

You can also specify a custom parameter so you know from which field the event is triggered.

Comment: the KISS principle! will remember :)

Answer (score 0):

There’s an event to trigger when tab gets collapsed/expanded, you can validate all the mandatory 13 fields when user collapse the tab1 or expand the tab2. If validation fails expand the tab1 & show notification, otherwise fine.